# Adding dataset identifier variable in full_join in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to automatically add a new dataset identifier variable when using `full_join()` in R.

```
df1 <- tribble(~ID, ~x,
"A", 1,
"B", 2,
"C", 3)

df2 <- tribble(~ID, ~y,
"D", 4,
"E", 5,
"F", 6)

combined <- df1 %>% dplyr::full_join(df2)
```

I know from `?full_join` that it joins all rows from df1 followed by df2. But, I couldn't find an option to create an index variable automatically.

Currently, I'm adding an extra variable in df1 first

```
df1 <- tribble(~ID, ~x, ~dataset,
    "A", 1, 1,
    "B", 2, 1,
    "C", 3, 1)
```

and following it up with `df1 %>% dplyr::full_join(df2) %>% dplyr::mutate(dataset = replace_na(dataset, 2))`

Any suggestions to do it in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's more efficient than  yours', but if there always do not exist overlapping columns except `id`, then you may try

```
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2) %>%
  mutate(dataset = as.numeric(is.na(x))+1)

  ID        x     y dataset
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         1    NA       1
2 B         2    NA       1
3 C         3    NA       1
4 D        NA     4       2
5 E        NA     5       2
6 F        NA     6       2
```

But to be safe, it might be better just define it's index(?) thing beforehand.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(dataset = 1) %>%
  full_join(df2 %>% mutate(dataset = 2))

  ID        x     y dataset
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         1    NA       1
2 B         2    NA       1
3 C         3    NA       1
4 D        NA     4       2
5 E        NA     5       2
6 F        NA     6       2
```

## New data

```
df1 <- tribble(~ID, ~x,~y,
               "A", 1,1,
               "B", 2,1,
               "C", 3,1)

df2 <- tribble(~ID, ~x,~y,
               "D", 4,1,
               "E", 5,1,
               "F", 6,1)

full_join(df1, df2)

  ID        x     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     1
2 B         2     1
3 C         3     1
4 D         4     1
5 E         5     1
6 F         6     1
```

Comment: I agree with the second option. I was more keen to know whether I'm missing any default option in `full_join()` itself. How will it affect when there are overlapping columns - won't it help to use `by` option in that case?

Comment: @Enigma The trick in your code, `mutate(dataset = replace_na(dataset, 2))` and in mine `mutate(dataset = as.numeric(is.na(x))+1)` assuming that there exist non-overlapping column, so we can differentiate `df1` and `df2` by `NA`s. I take a look at [join function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/join), but I cannot find another way that directly add index by data.

Comment: I might be missing a point here - what happens if we do have overlapping columns? I tried but it still works!

Comment: @Enigma I think it depends on it's data. I add some overlapping data above.

Comment: Yeah, my point was even in that case the code given by you works fine in adding index column. I was chasing, **if there always do not exist overlapping columns** part in your original answer :) .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a "join", maybe try `bind_rows` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "dataset")
```

This will bind rows, and the missing columns are filled in with `NA`. In addition, you can specify an ".id" argument with an identifier. If you provide a list of dataframes, the labels are taken from names in the list. If not, a numeric sequence is used (as seen below).

**Output**

```
  dataset ID        x     y
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1       A         1    NA
2 1       B         2    NA
3 1       C         3    NA
4 2       D        NA     4
5 2       E        NA     5
6 2       F        NA     6
```

Comment: I am trying to get my head around the difference between `bind_rows()` and `full_join()`. Could you please explain when do we prefer `bind_rows()` over `full_join()`?

Comment: I suppose I assumed there was no common key between the two datasets. If there isn’t and you just wanted to add rows of one dataset to the other, then bind_rows could work. However, if you do have a common key, and may have the same ID value present in two different datasets, then full_join could be more appropriate. In the example above, it sounded like different IDs between the 2 sets. Is that true?

Comment: You're correct - in my example the data had all unique IDs. However, I was just comparing other scenario for my learning!